# Color determination with python matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to prepare the tillson t3 strategy with python. How can I print "Red" for Downtrend and "Green" for Uptrend?

I want the green line in the attached picture to change to red if the drop has come. There is an example on Tradingview
[image]

https://tr.tradingview.com/script/QpkypNjA/

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
filename = 'credentials.txt'
connection = BinanceConnection(filename)
interval = '1d'
pair = 'BTCUSDT'
limit = 500

klines = connection.client.get_klines(symbol=pair, interval=interval, limit=limit)
open_time = [int(entry[0]) for entry in klines]

open = [float(entry[1]) for entry in klines]
high = [float(entry[2]) for entry in klines]
low = [float(entry[3]) for entry in klines]
close = [float(entry[4]) for entry in klines]

close_array = np.asarray(close)
high_array = np.asarray(high)
low_array = np.asarray(low)

new_time = [datetime.fromtimestamp(time / 1000) for time in open_time]

new_time_x = [date.strftime("%y-%m-%d") for date in new_time]

volume_factor = 0.7
t3length = 8
tillsont3 = generateTillsonT3(close_array, high_array, low_array, volume_factor=volume_factor, t3Length=t3length)

plt.figure(figsize=(11, 6))
plt.plot(new_time_x[400:], close_array[400:], label='Price')
plt.plot(new_time_x[400:], tillsont3[400:], label='Tillson T3')
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.title("Tillson T3 Plot for BTC/USDT")
plt.xlabel("Open Time")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('demo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: I think [this page](https://www.onbirkod.com/tillson-t3-indikatorunu-python-ile-yazalim/) will be very helpful.

Comment: yes I have reviewed this site, but here, I could not change the color.